# Display different values on axis than those found by the scale function in D3

Tags: d3.js

I have a d3 graph that uses a linear scale for its x axis. It looks something like this:

```
  ...
y |
  |
  +-------------------------------------------
  0.0   0.5    1.0    1.5    2.0    2.5    3.0
                  Time in weeks
```

Beneath this axis I want to display rows of data aligned to the x axis. Like this:

```
  23    23            22                   19
```

Using this data:

```
var nums = [23, 23, 22, 19];
var times = [0, 0.5, 1.5, 3];
```

`times` are where the `nums` should fall on the `Time in weeks` x axis. So the first index of `nums` falls under `0.0`, the second under `0.5`, and so on.

The scale function looks something like this:

```
var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0,3]).range([0, 600]);
```

So `x(0.5)` returns the correct range value for displaying a tick on the new axis. But what I want to display is the corresponding value from the `nums` array. That is, display the value of `nums[times.indexOf(0.5)]`.

Is there a way to override `scale()` as used by `d3.svg.axis()` so that it displays `nums` values instead of `times` values while still using `times` as the input domain?

**Edit**

[Here is a demo](http://jsbin.com/ocugeg/2/edit)

**Edit 2**

I figured it out thanks to ne8il's answer. The answer was not complete, but it formed the basis for this code:

```
var x1Axis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x1)
      .ticks(nums)
      .tickValues(times)
      .tickFormat(function(x){return nums[times.indexOf(x)];})
```

[Working example](http://jsbin.com/ocugeg/4/edit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe in this case you can do

```
d3.svg.axis().ticks(times).tickValues(nums);
```

It will pass each 'time' into your scale function to map it to an x coordinate, and use the corresponding indexed value in 'nums' to output text.
[Source is here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#wiki-tickValues)

Comment: Passing an array to `axis.ticks()` doesn't seem to be supported in linear scales (see [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#wiki-ticks)). At any rate, this code doesn't work. I'll try to code up an example for you.

Comment: Glad to be of any help. If you can move the 'nums' into the data array itself you can rely on that rather than the hardcoded data arrays, like here : http://jsbin.com/ocugeg/8/edit . Not sure how helpful that is but I was playing around with it.

Comment: Yes, that's a better data structure, but the application I'm working on has a different data structure entirely, so I simply extract `times` and `nums` using `.map()`.